# Complications reverse engineering a Visual Basic application

Tags: crackme, visual-basic

I'm reverse engineering a Visual Basic application and I've run into a big of a sticky situation, so I was hoping that someone might have an opinion on a way to approach it. It's basically a crackme but I haven't been able to nail down where the callback code is for the function I'm looking for. I've found the labels and captions but I was hoping for an intelligent way to start looking at the binary instead of crawling through it from top to bottom until I find the right comparison.

I've taken a look at the output of VB Decompiler but the output isn't matching up to what I'm used to.

[image: here's the output from VB Decompiler]

In other VB apps it seems like the locations given there is enough to get started and find the callbacks, but not with this one: [image: this is what I get when trying to find any of the actual code].

I thought at first the code was just being rendered poorly in the debugger but after playing around with it I don't think that location is correct at all. So I'm looking for ideas on where to go from here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably P-code compiled file, not native code. Try WKT Debugger:

http://www.woodmann.com/collaborative/tools/index.php/Whiskey_Kon_Tequilla_VB_P-Code_Debugger

Comment: This gives me an error whenever I try to run it about missing DLLs. I couldn't find copies online and I saw something about the debugger only erroring out if the application isn't pcode compiled?

Comment: I take what I said before back. I must have had a corrupt download the first time around or something. I tried again and that gave me enough information to get what I was looking for.